# how to split string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'd like to split a string with using pattern like this:

it starts and ends with '\n' and contains an arbitrary number of whitespace or '\n' in between.

Edit:

This input:

```
string s = "aaa\n    \nbbb\n    \nccc\n   \n   \nddd";
```

should result in an array containing

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Comment: Please edit your post to provide some sample input, and the output you'd like to obtain. As written, it seems very unclear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the one example given, the following would accomplish the specified results:

```
string str = "aaa\n   \nbbb\n   \nccc\n   \n   \nddd";
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, "\n\\s*");
```

Answer (score 5):

Given your example, `string.Split` will be much cleaner.

```
var vals = s.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I think this leaves array entries with spaces.  Should the first parameter maybe be:  `new char[] { '\n', ' ' }`?